# How fast would torrents be at 10 mbps

Tags: internet, bittorrent

I'm planing on getting a 10 mbps internet but I'm not sure how fast that would be, and I am not talking about loading a web page.

With my current internet I get 500-900 kbps download when downloading a torrent file, and if I'm luck I get 1 mbps.

So how much mbps would be the torrent download on a 10 mpbs internet ?

PS. It would be connected via ethernet cable while on my current it isn't.

Comment: How can we possibly give an accurate answer to this because it totally depends on whether your ISP performs any traffic shaping, the time you download/number of users on your exchange, the torrent peers you're using (they'll have all of the above, too), whether they set speed limits on peers... the list is endless...

Comment: 10 mbps is 10 millibits per second, which will transfer about one byte every 15 minutes. Are you sure you don't mean Mbps? Getting the capitalisation is critically important for metric prefixes.

Comment: It's also quite possible he means 10 MB/sec, an order of magnitude different again from 10 Mb/sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be aware of MBps vs Mbps here:

Utorrent reads Bytes
Service Providers sell Bits

So a 10 Megabit connection will give 1.25 Megabyte per second (or 1250KB/s) maximum download speed. In real world terms there are overheads though so expect maybe 90% of that (Say 1.1MB/s). If you're currently peaking at 900KB/s it wont be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

My experiences were that good, healthy torrent maxed out at about 1.2 MBps with old 11 Mbps connection. Which is not exactly on par with ~3 MBps on my current 40Mbps cable, but that's probably due to the fact that I'm maxing out other peoples upload bandwith, and not everyone has access to more than 5-10 Mbps of that.

Comment: I think the downvotes are in response to the max speed of 11 Mbps being 1.375 MB/s, so getting 2 MB/s download would be impossible. However it is useful that you mentioned that torrents have other limitations on their speed i.e. the bandwidth of seeders.

Comment: Good call on the 2MBps - I got back from extended stay in different country where comma is decimal so need to edit so it would say 1.2 MBps.

As for the rest - it is quite impossible to count all limitations as mentioned. And I think mentioning first hand experience would trump that list anyway?